# Can because appear in the start of a sentence?

Tags: verbs, nouns, conjunctions, parts-of-speech, clauses

I am usually used to writing because in the middle of a sentence during my school days. But nowadays I find that because also appears in the start of a sentence. Even if because is used in the start of a sentence, should there be a comma? For example: Because he was so attached to this book, he didn't get the mindset to lend it to anyone. Or is it fine if there is no comma in the example? Kindly guide me.

Comment: The example given is fine, and the comma would generally be recommended for that case.  I'm guessing there would be cases where a comma would be less appropriate, in a reason/consequence sentence, but I can't come up with an example right now.

Comment: Because of sentences constructed this way, you shouldn't always use a comma.